# Can we perform location based task when app is terminated in react-native?

Tags: react-native, background

Is there a way by which we can perform location based task (geofence) in background when the app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
   AppState.addEventListener('change', 
   this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
   if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
     // Here you can do anything like Geolocation or logging
  }    
 }
```

Comment: I have tried but it not working. The thing is it is ok for direct approach but in my case the geolocation code is in parent class and on the condition bases i call the api from the child class using it reference. But when the app is terminated the reference will be null so won't be able to perform action.

Comment: I'm using this code in my chat app for sending some message to all users !